# MySQLI Select from table using prepared statments

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am currently in the process of changing all my old MySQL to MySQLI. However, I'm having a problem when trying to SELECT from a table when using prepared statements. Tags is a string.

My test URL is:

```
http://example.com/retreiveCustomArticle.php?Tags=the
```

My Output:

```
string(3) "the" string(44) "SELECT `ID` FROM `Articles` WHERE `Tags` = ?" Success!: 0
```

Code:

```
<?php
//Open a new connection to the MySQL server
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','createyo_james','password','createyo_TestDatabase');

//Output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//values to be inserted in database table
$Tags = $_GET["Tags"];

var_dump($_GET["Tags"]);

$query = "SELECT `ID`, `NewsStory`, `Summary1`, `Summary2` FROM `Articles` WHERE `Tags` = ?";

$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
var_dump($query);
//bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
$statement->bind_param('s', $Tags);

if($statement->execute()){

$result = $stmt -> get_result();

/* bind result variables */
$stmt->bind_result($ID,$NewsStory,$Summary1,$Summary2);

/* fetch values */
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
$output[]=array($ID,$NewsStory,$Summary1,$Summary2);
}

print(json_encode($output));
$stmt -> close();
}else{
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
}
$statement->close();

?>
```

Comment: What is the problem? I don't see anything wrong here...

Comment: could you be more specific about your error?

Comment: I'm not receiving an error. Instead i just do not receive the intended output.

Comment: What is the intended output?

Comment: To receive the JSON of a few records in the table.

Comment: The `ID` field is JSON data?

Comment: your select statement is only asking for one field from the table, but your `bind_result` is binding 4 fields, that will throw an error.

Comment: Ok i have updated it to the matching 4. I'm not sure if the syntax is correct though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @VotetoClose said, I suggest you this:

```
$statement=$mysqli->prepare('SELECT ID FROM Articles WHERE Tags = ?');
$mysqli->execute(array($_GET['Tags']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `bind_result()` and `fetch()`

```
if($statement->execute()){
    if ($statement->bind_result($theId)) { // $theId will be the result that is returned from the database
        if ($statement->fetch()) { // if fetched successfully
             print 'Success!: ' . $theId . '<br />'; // do this
```

Comment: I actually wanted to output a JSON format. Would i still need to do this. Have updated question.